# How to prevent dropping on a list with VueDraggable (sortable.js)

Tags: javascript, vue.js, sortablejs

I've been looking for a while but I can't figure out how to prevent *only* dropping on a list (using multiple lists). What I'm looking to achieve is basically a size limit on a list. When it exceeds the limit, it should prevent dropping but allow dragging to another list.

Not sure if this is very simple but I can't find a way of doing it. Maybe there's an option for this or something?

Thanks!

Comment: Why not use Sortable's `sort` option to disable it after a certain size is reached? https://sortablejs.github.io/Sortable/#sorting-disabled

Comment: Ended up using put, but that got me the answer. Thanks!